# How do I compute the expected value of this sequence of R.V.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

> Let the sample space be $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma algebra and the
>   probability dx:
>
> $X(\omega)= \frac {1}  {1-\omega}$.
>
> Define $X_n(w) = min(X(w),n)$. Show that $X_n \uparrow X$ $a.s.$, and that
>   $E[X_n]\uparrow E[X]$

Here is my attempt. First, I know that $E[X]=+\infty$. From the definition of $X_n$ we can see that :

$$
X_n(w) =
\begin{cases}
X(w),  & \text{for $ 0\le w \le \frac {n-1}{n}$ } \\
n, & \text{for $\frac {n-1}{n}< w  \le 1$ } \\
\end{cases}
$$

From this we can see that $X_n \uparrow X$ $a.s.$. Then I can use the monotone convergence theorem to claim that $E[X_n]\uparrow E[X]$. But I want to really check that $E[X_n]\uparrow E[X]$ by computing $E[X_n]$. Is the following expression correct?
$$E[X_n]=\int_0^{\frac {n-1}{n}} \frac 1 {1-\omega} d\omega + \int_\frac {n-1}{n}^{1} n  d\omega$$
Is this correct? How do I show that this sequence converges to $E[X]$? I think I should take the limit, but it looks like it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

What you have done is correct. To see that $EX_n \to \infty$ just note that (by direct evaluation of the integral)  $EX_n \geq \int_0^{1-\frac 1 n} \frac 1 {1-\omega} d\omega =\ln n \to \infty$.

$\int_0^{1-\frac 1 n} \frac 1 {1-\omega} d\omega =-\ln (1-\omega)|_0^{1-\frac 1 n} =-\ln (\frac 1n)=ln \, n$

Comment: $ \int\limits_\frac {n-1}{n}^{1} n \, d\omega$ is even simpler as it is $1$

Comment: @Henry We are supposed to show that $EX_n \to \infty$.

Comment: Indeed, so you have $EX_n \ge \ln n \to \infty$ while doing the very simple integral would give $EX_n = 1+ \ln n \to \infty$.  Both lead to the same answer